# What do you call a person who is used by a manager/boss in order to keep their employment?

Tags: names, business-language, management

A person on probation was told to lie by his manager. If they did not comply with the mangers demands, they would have failed their probation, thus, would be unable to remain employed.

Are there any specific names for both the manager and the probationary worker in this kind of scenario? This is similar to the casting couch or metoo movement, but rather than sexual favours, this scenario asks a male or female to lie or commit other immoral acts in order to gain continued employment in the office. Is there a name for this scenario?

Comment: What is the context in which you plan to use the word/phrase?

Comment: The context is to highlight serious managerial corruption at my work place. This immediately left an impression of casting couch on me, but the relevant word eluded me. This is for a report I am sending.

Comment: This is a form of blackmail. You could try *blackmailer* and *blackmailee*. But though they *are* both real words, but the latter is not very common.

Answer (score 1):

One term that can be used is

> **exploitation**
> the act of using someone unfairly for your own advantage
>
> *Marx wrote about the exploitation of the workers.*
> *She favors legislation to curb the exploitation of child labour.*

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/exploitation).

Another general word for this is

> **abuse**
> to use something for the wrong purpose in a way that is harmful or morally wrong

from which specific names for the manager and the worker can be derived:

> the abuser
> the abused

Again, from [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/abuse).

Comment: Thanks for the above.  The original name for this scenario that came to mind was old boys' network" or "boys' club, but I think that was way off the mark.  Exploitation seems more appropriate.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, [old boy network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_boy_network) is off the mark. It is about getting advantage because of your social connections. Almost the reverse of your scenario – one benefit is being excused formalities and requirements, not their imposition.